# Angular JS in MVC nglick not workinf

Tags: angularjs

I have created a MVC web application with a cshtml page for registering user details.
    I have a created a Database in SQL server and Data access layer.
    Created a model class.
    created controller class and exposed a method to be called from Angularjscontroller.js  .
    created Angularjscontroller.js file .
    in the cshtml file , a button control is defined. In ng-click of it, I called the function savedata which is defined in Angularjscontroller.js .but ng-click does not fire.

```
HomeAngular.js file
------------------

var app = angular. Module("Homeapp", []);
app.controller("HomeController", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.Savedata = function () {
               $http(
            {
                method: POST,
                url: '/Home/AddMembers',
                data: $scope.RegisterUser
                )}.success(function (d) {
                   $scope.RegisterUser = null;
            alert(d);
        )}.error(function ()
    {
        alert('failed');
    })

    }

 });

    Registermembers.cshtml
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        ----------------------
         <div class="container" ng-app="Homeapp"  ng-controller="HomeController">
         <div  class="col-md-3">

        <input type="button" ng-click="Savedata()" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
         </div>
        </div>
      <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="~/Scripts/Angular Controller/HomeAngularJs.js"></script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Cause there is syntax errors in your code. that's why it not called. Check your developer console.

Comment: console does not show any errors...and there is no tag mismatch as well I have checked...the code also built properly..when I enter all the values in the page and click also...how can I see the errors if not shown in the console...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your syntax errors. Compare this below code with yours.

```js
var app = angular.module("Homeapp", []);
app.controller("HomeController", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.Savedata = function() {
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/Home/AddMembers',
      data: $scope.RegisterUser
    }).success(function(d) {
      $scope.RegisterUser = null;
      alert(d);
    }).error(function() {
      alert('failed');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class="container" ng-app="Homeapp" ng-controller="HomeController">
    <div class="col-md-3">

      <input type="button" ng-click="Savedata()" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Ramakrishnan Accept it as answer if this helps you.